# Failed to load 'Flutter' podspec

Tags: flutter

Flutter is weirdly changing the file `Flutter.podspec` during the `flutter run` command. It is applying a template which is badly formatted and as a result, the compilation process gets stuck.

```
#
# NOTE: This podspec is NOT to be published. It is only used as a local source!
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Flutter'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'High-performance, high-fidelity mobile apps.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
Flutter provides an easy and productive way to build and deploy high-performance mobile apps for Android and iOS.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'https:
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT' }
  s.author           = { 'Flutter Dev Team' => 'flutter-dev@googlegroups.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https:
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Flutter.framework'
end
```

Comment: The issue is limited to the parameters `s.homepage` and `s.source` and once I enclose the string using `'`, things come back to normality.

Comment: An issue has been raised within Flutter team https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58283